# when I resume app by Custom URL scheme first time,the window.handleOpenURL doesn't execute

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, custom-scheme-url

When I start app by custom scheme url,event 'deviceready' trigger,and window.handleOpenURL in the getBillFromLink() execute;

then I open a webpage and resume the app from it,but window.handleOpenURL didn't execute;function onResume and getBillFromLink will execute;

but no matter how many times I resume the app from webpage after the first time,
window.handleOpenURL will execute normally；

Here are code:

```
$ionicPlatform.on("deviceready", function () {
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    getBillFromLink().then(function (data) {
        //todo
    });
});
function onResume() {
    getBillFromLink().then(function (data) {
        //todo
    });
}
function getBillFromLink() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {
        window.handleOpenURL = function(url){
            if(!!url){
                 deferred.resolve(url);
            }else{
                 deferred.reject(url);
            }
        };
    }, 0);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

how could I deal with the trouble?

thanks for your advice and sorry for my poor English:-)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not linked to custom-scheme-url plugin as your apps properly starts when you call your specific URL.

I assume that, once the app is already started; custom-scheme-url does not trigger again your function.

You have to use a backgroundmode plugin.
I suggest to use : https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

This plugin let s you define events when apps goes from background to active app. and more.